# Audio amplifier with MIX3001 IC

Tags: amplifier, audio

I have a MIX3001 audio IC with which I want to make a small audio amplifier with volume control with a 5-pin round dial potentiometer.

Referring to its datasheet I can understand the application, but I don't know how should I add the volume control since the potentiometer is a 5-pin one, and I am not quite aware of the implementation.

Also, I would like to know a few things concerning the image:

1. What is that triangular flag representing?
2. How should I add a push button for muting the system?

[image: IC Application from the Datasheet]

[Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1804240820_Shanghai-Mixinno-Microelectronics-MIX3001_C15182.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

1. Analog ground.
2. Switch to ground. It has built-in pull up so just leave the switch open to not mute it.